# Can I set a global value from a method?

Tags: ruby, global-variables

I'm wondering if there is a way for me to configure a global variable from a method, for example:

```
Class myExample
  $my_global_variable = 0

  def initialize
    change_my_global_variable
  end

  def change_my_global_variable
     $my_global_variable = 2
  end
end


Class myExample2 < myExample

 @this_value = $my_global_variable
 #I want @this_value to be set to 2
end

#Updated:
#Currently when I tried what i have above I get the following:
#@this_value = 0 instead of 2
```

I'm working with really old code and I need to change the value of the global variable after it loads since it needs to pull the value from the function.  Is there a way that i can initialize a global variable that will be changed?  Currently "$my_global_variable" never changes, it keeps the value 0

Comment: Please post valid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your method is never being invoked, otherwise, it would work.

Your method is called in `initialize`, but no new instance of `myExample` or `myExample2` is ever made, so your initialization and method call never happens.

Here is one way around this:

```
Class myExample2 < myExample
  @this_value = change_my_global_variable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, you can change global variables from within methods. However, you never call the method which changes the global variable, so it will never get changed. You need to call the method somewhere.